Have any (other) countries declared parts of the UN terrorist groups?
AP:

Qatar and Saudi Arabia on Sunday condemned an Israeli parliamentary bill that seeks to label UNRWA, the main provider of aid for Palestinians in Gaza, a terrorist group, joining a growing number of nations opposed to the proposal.
The bill, which passed a preliminary vote in parliament last week, is the product of increasingly tense relations between Israel and the United Nations agency for Palestinian refugees. Israel has accused the agency of militant links, claiming that hundreds of its employees are members of militant groups, including some who allegedly participated in the Oct. 7 attacks on southern Israel. [...]
The bill moving through parliament seeks to brand the agency a “terror group,” saying that the employees’ alleged involvement in the Hamas assault shows that “it is a terror organization that is no different from the Hamas terror organization.” The bill also seeks to cut diplomatic ties between Israel and the agency.
The bill passed the initial vote 42-6 and must go through committees and three other votes before becoming law.

I know UN peacekeepers and what not were involved in some scandals before. But has any other country declared an organization part of the UN to be a terrorist group, as a whole? There were a few countries with whom the UN was probably very unpopular at times, e.g. the UN technically invaded North Korea in the 1950s etc. (Although it was mostly US troops.) Have any such countries reacted with declaring the UN or parts thereof terrorist though?

Maybe "tried to declare" might better reflect the current state of affair wrt Israel.  Until the law actually passes or is rejected it really should be compared to other countries were some lawmakers have tried to pass such as law, as well as those that have succeeded.  In fact, maybe just hold off till the law passes, because there is nothing all that all unusual about bad laws getting nuked in parliaments without going any further.

The bill, which passed a preliminary vote in Knesset last week, is not expected to progress further, according to Hebrew media reports, which suggest the coalition intends to derail it down the line.

Also, not sure what Qatar and Saudi Arabia have to do with legislative process in Israel, and to what extent they represent the majority of the nations (do Qatar and Saudi Arabia ever say anything positive about the Zionist entity?)
